# Python: be sure only to get one element from lambda back

Tags: python, lambda, filter

I have the following filter in my code:

```
id = 4     
for result in filter(lambda list: list['id'] == id, list):
    pass #do something with the result
```

List is a list of dictionaries. It may be that there are duplicates in the list. How can I limit the number of results to 1?

Comment: This is not a question about lambda. This is a question about *`filter()`*, or more generally, about iterators.

Comment: You are basically asking: *how to check that an iterator returns at most one element*.

Comment: Or do you want just the first match and don't care if there are more?

Comment: I'm going with the latter explanation for now, and found you a suitable duplicate. TLDR: `result = next(filter(lambda list: list['id'] == id, list), None)` would give you the first match, or `None` if there were no matches.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, it's exactly the latter I want to achieve, also the other option is also interesting as learning experience (maybe for others).